# Calculating length of a generalized range

Tags: python

I started writing a class called `grange` that serves as a generalized range -- create a range of dates, etc.

Calculating the length of a range of integers is easy: `(stop - start)//step`:

`len(range(0, 8, 2))` -> `(8 - 0)//2` -> `(8)//2` -> 4

Of course, dealing with negative steps and start > stop is a bit trickier, but the general idea holds.

But when I moved from the concrete realm of integers to the abstract realm of "things" my mind started to melt.

Let's assume a few things:

- Start, Stop, Step all have `__add__`, `__sub__` and `__truediv__` defined, are interoperable between the objects.
- When combined like: `(start - stop + step)//step` we get a bare number (int, float, complex, etc).
- Start, Stop or Step + 1 may raise a TypeError, i.e. `timedelta(days=1) + 1`

Here's what I currently have:

```
def __len__(self):
    if self.stop is None:
        # 10/10 wish float('inf') was returnable
        raise TypeError("Infinite Range!")
    try:
        # factor in self.step to compensate to include start position
        if self._has_neg_step:
            calc = self.start - self.stop - self.step
        else:
            calc = self.stop - self.start + self.step
        # counteract float and negative steps
        return int(abs(calc//self.step))
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        # throw a hail mary!
        # seems dangerous but should be *alright* since
        # bail out on infinite sequence case
        return len(list(iter(self)))
```

This works great for dates!

```
start, stop = datetime(2015, 3, 1), datetime(2015, 3, 8)
step = timedelta(days=2)
assert len(grange(start, stop, step)) == 4
```

But with integers...

```
assert len(grange(0,8,1)) == 8, len(grange(0, 8, 1))
AssertationError: 9
```

Originally, I had considered coming up with an abstraction over one:

```
self._one = step//step
```

So I could just do:

```
(self.stop - self.start - self.step + self.one)//self.step
```

A thing divided by itself is one! Thank you elementary school! But there's an issue: `timedelta(days=2)//timedelta(days=2) == 1` not `timedelta(days=1)`

Turns out I forgot the part where `x unit/x unit` also cancels out the unit part, too. At least for timedelta. Who knows what other objects will do?

I'm not convinced that with the implementation that a generalized algorithm is possible (or maybe even at all!) but bailing straight to: `len(list(iter(self)))` seems wasteful but that also seems like the only foolproof solution.

It seems like a compromise would be to calculate the length once using `len(list(iter(self)))` and stash it in a property:

```
# works because Python will bypass __getattribute__ when len is called.
@property
def __len__(self):
    if self.stop is None:
        raise TypeError('Infinite range')
    if not hasattr(self, '__len__'):
        self.__len__ = len(list(iter(self))
    return self.__len__
```

This removes many of the assumptions about the passed objects.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I posted a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619851/representing-a-range-of-values-as-a-python-sequence-type) a while ago (which sadly didn't get a  lot of traction) that you might be interested in.  I'd be curious to see your final implementation as well, if you care to share it anywhere.

Comment: Your examples between dates and integers are confusing, could you post examples with both types using the same range and skip values (e.g. `irange(1,8,2)`)?  I suspect your problem is not limited to integer types.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Python 3.x? With 2.7, I'm getting an error for `//` with `timedelta`

Comment: @tobias_k I'm working with 3.4.0 right now, but I'm going to work back to 2.6 and 3.2 when I have something that works. Maybe using truediv instead of floordiv would be better...

Comment: @dimo414 I'm checking it out now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with the types: in `len(grange(0,8,1))` the 8 is counted for the length as well (so 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 is 9 numbers). This isn't occurring for your dates example because you can't get to 8 starting from 1 with a step of 2.

So if calc is a multiple (multiplicative? English is not my native tongue) of step, (normal div, not truediv) subtract length by 1.

TL;DR your len acts as if the grange includes the stop, but you expect it to exclude the stop giving unexpected results.

Comment: In the "normal" python `range` builtin, the `stop` number is _exclusive_. I guess it should be the same for `grange`, i.e. `grange(0,8,1)` should yield `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

Comment: @tobias_k That's exactly the problem I'm pointing out, isn't it? His __len__ function acts as if it was inclusive yet he is expecting exclusive.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm testing out a modified version right now and it seems to be working.